# SimPy: Is it possible to create an Exclusive OR (OneOf) alternative to AnyOf which allows only one process to be triggered?

Tags: simpy

I would like to be able to trigger exactly one process in a list, and interrupt the other processes in the list. In the example below I want to trigger either A or B, but never both. The example below works, fine except when waitingtimeA = waitingtimeB.

```
import simpy
from simpy import AnyOf

def waitingprocess(env, waitingtime):
    try: 
        yield env.timeout(waitingtime)
    except:
        pass

def example(env):
    waitingtimeA = 1.0
    waitingtimeB = 1.0
    A = env.process(waitingprocess(env, waitingtimeA))
    B = env.process(waitingprocess(env, waitingtimeB))
    events = [A,B]
    yield AnyOf(env, events)
    for e in events:
        if not e.processed:
            e.interrupt()
    print('is A Processed:', A.processed)
    print('is B Processed:', B.processed)

    
env = simpy.Environment()
Example = env.process(example(env))
env.run()
```

Which should lead to either A or B being processed, but which prints:

```
is A Processed: True
is B Processed: True
```

I understand that both processes A and B are triggered and processed before the Example process continues, but is there a way around this to make processes A and B trigger mutually exclusive?

The only thing I can think of is to make a OneOf() alternative of AnyOf(), which as soon as exactly one event is triggered, interrupts all other events. For this to work the OneOf() Condition Event must be an URGENT event (an event with higher priority than normal events). However, I am kind of out of my depth. Does anyone have an idea where to start?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No. The problem is in your example you do not have exactly one event trigger, both events triggers happen at the same point in time.  I know simpy is single threaded, but I think the state of both events are updated before its get to your code.  I had the same problem when trying to get one resource from two resource pools.  When I got one resource I had to check the other resource request and cancel it if it had not fired, or release it if it had fired.